# way to populate number of rows in mysql without selecting table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am looking for a way to populate values in row in mysql 
for example if i execute query

```
select 1,2,3,4
```

it gives response

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

that is in *row*
is there a possible way to produce this data in *column*
like

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Try UNION or UNION ALL.

Comment: You seem to be confused about what is a row, and what is a column

Comment: @forpas can I ask to you why do you not insert an answer instead of comment?

Comment: @user2342558 Some questions are just too trivial

Comment: @user2342558 because *try something* (in this case which is easy to solve) is more useful to the OP.

Comment: @forpas thanks, I was curious :)

Comment: .. also keep in mind, well this is possible do not misuse this to generate data if you for example could easy do it in your application with a array for example..

Comment: well i can use select 1 as q union all  select 2 as q union all select 3 as q union all select 4 as q; but if i need to populate 100 rows

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of Recursive with clause in MySQL version 8.0 or higher, We now have a row generator in MySQL -

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_count (n) 
AS (
      SELECT 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT n + 1 
      FROM cte_count 
      WHERE n < 100
    )
SELECT n 
FROM cte_count;
```

Before version 8.0 MySQL doesn't have any inbuilt row_generator functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want values in a column, you can use:

```
select 1 as n union all
select 2 as n union all
select 3 as n union all
select 4 as n
```

This construct is often used in derived tables (or more recently in CTEs).

If you just need a set number of values, then an existing table (that is big enough) can be used:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as n
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
limit 4;
```